# How to upgrade my PC

Tags: upgrade, intel-core-i5

I have an old PC with the following configuration.

```
Intel Core 2 Duo
Intel 945GCCR Motherboard
```

I want to upgrade it to the following configuration.

```
Core i5 ( 4th Gen)
Any Intel motherboard.
4 GB RAM ( Expandable upto 8 GB)
```

Do I need to change my CPU cabinet, hard disk or anything else while making the above change?
My monitor supports DVI and VGA.

Comment: The motherboard, and the ram minimum. There might be other smaller conciderations depending on the model chosen, like PS2 input devcies, checking compatability with the monitor connection type your using, and insuring an Aged psu can cope.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have updated my question and I have both keyboard and mouse. My main concern is what else need to change in making PC. ( Like CPU cabinet , processor fan , power supply)

Comment: Ahh, forgot that, case screw locations have not changed (you still want to watch for errant standoffs). fans they are using more PWM based 4 pin, but it is all compatable still.  The heatsink would depend on the one you have.  PSU are now usually 24pin MB connects, i think that is the same, plus the 4-6-8pin 12V connect on the motherboard.  Old molex connections can be adapted to sata fairly easily.  Power consumptions have lowered some, but aged PSUs are aged :-)

Comment: Old Front case connections do not support USB 3.0 , switch and led stuff and front audio mostly the same. Usually there is a USB2.0 you could still pass to the front.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider buying a completely new PC with the specifications you need. Such an upgrade does not make huge sense because you will then have other components that are the bottleneck (like HDD) and slowing down your i5.

And you may run into other problems like the compatiblity of your case or power supply.